# Locale in springboot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I trying to use I18N in my spring-boot 2 application

First I create a file named 'messages_pt_BR.properties' in my resource/locale/messages  with:

```
Size.Ato.sercicos=Deve conter pelo menos 1 item
Size.atoRtdpj.servicos=Deve conter pelo menos 1 item
Size.servicos=msg1
Size=msg2
validacao_documento_obrigatorio=Documento: Pelo menos 1 precisa estar preenchido
```

Then I create

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pt","BR")); // without this line when I try to get the locale the system return en_BR
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pt","BR"));
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:locale/messages");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600); //refresh cache once per hour
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

then I create

```
@Component
public class Messages {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    public String getMessage(String id) {
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        return messageSource.getMessage(id,null,locale);
    }

}
```

so in my controller I use:

```
@Autowired
Messages messages;

//in my method:

messages.getMessage("validacao_documento_obrigatorio")
```

when I try to test this return this error:

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'validacao_documento_obrigatorio' for locale 'pt_BR'.
```

And the jpa constraint don't changes to.

Comment: Your classpath is not defined correct, please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `messages_pt_BR.properties` under `locale` if you would like to load from `classpath:locale/messages` as this will search your `messages_pt_BR property` under locale folder so if you want under `/locale/messages` then you need to pass full file name path like below as it will load `messages_pt_BR` file under `/locale/messages` folder:

```
 @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:locale/messages/messages");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600); //refresh cache once per hour
        return messageSource;
    }
```

Comment: Tks mans work, but more one question if in this  file I put Size.myClass.myPropert=my new message, don`t have to change the message when I use @validate in my controller? tks

Comment: That’s great, I believe you are referring @validation as for Valid annotation you need to define validations on your pojo and it will work for your request body in controller if you annotate Valid..

Comment: Just one more thing if my answer help you to resolve problem, kindly accept the answer so other can take benefit if they face same issue

Comment: The answer helps, tks.  and I using annotations in my project, I put one @Size(min=1)List<MyClass> servicos; and in message_pt_BR I try to use Size=new message try Size.MyClass.servicos=new message and the message don't change when I send a json without(or null) property servico

Comment: Use @Size(min=1, message=“${property name}” and in your controller before request body use Valid notation

Comment: Or it would be great if you can post another question so I can look what actually you are using and can provide solution as in comment section I am not able to put exact code, if you post other question please let me know link so I can look at